# FusedLocation Pending Intent sometimes invoked without location

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I have an Intent Service that is invoked by FusedLocationApi every minute or so to monitor locations periodically via pending .

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {

            LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

        } else {
            Crashlytics.logException(new LocationException("Loc Intent Service invoked without location", new NullPointerException()));
        }
}
```

It is working fine most of the time but in production, in the last 7 days I have received 13,000 events of the service being invoked by the FusedLocationApi without any location. (thanks to the Crashlytics non fatal exception I've added)

Why or when would this happen? I have tried disabling location permission while the locations are being monitored, in which case the service *is* invoked without location but just once or twice, after which it is never invoked again until I turn location permission back on.

Comment: You are never guaranteed to receive a location in any case, you always need to check to see if the location is null or not.

Answer (score -1):

Per the [requestLocationUpdates() documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Both [`LocationResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult.html) and [`LocationAvailability`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability.html) are sent to the given PendingIntent. You can extract data from an Intent using [`hasResult(Intent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult.html#hasResult(android.content.Intent)), [`extractResult(Intent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult.html#extractResult(android.content.Intent)), [`hasLocationAvailability(Intent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability.html#hasLocationAvailability(android.content.Intent)), and [`extractLocationAvailability(Intent)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability.html#extractLocationAvailability(android.content.Intent)).

While you're checking the first case, you're not handling (or ignoring) changes in the location availability.